# How to get original position of an element (DIV) after it's been rotated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For a DIV which has been rotated using CSS transform.

I need get original position of an DIV (top, left, bottom, right, width, height)  before rotation was applied (look at gray div for an example).

http://jsfiddle.net/akycc4t1/7/

I know that I can remove CSS rotation and use [Element.getBoundingClientRect();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)
to get the value, but I was wondering if there is a better approach using math/geometry.

My needs is to re-create programmatically a DIV positioned exactly on top of the original one using coordinates relative to the top-left of the viewport.
Other methods or idea area also welcome.

```
<div id="example" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="target" class="rotation"></div>
<div id="trace"></div>
<button id="btn-rotate" type="button">rotate</button>
<button id="btn-coordinate" type="button">get coordinate x,y</button>
<button id="btn-coordinate-notrotated" type="button">get coordinate as target was not rotated</button>

document.getElementById('btn-rotate').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    document.getElementById('target').classList.add('rotation');
    document.getElementById('example').style.display = '';
}.bind(this));

document.getElementById('btn-coordinate').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(document.getElementById('target').getBoundingClientRect()));
}.bind(this));

document.getElementById('btn-coordinate').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(document.getElementById('target').getBoundingClientRect()));
}.bind(this));


document.getElementById('btn-coordinate-notrotated').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    // solution here    
    alert('{top: xxxx,left: xxxx, right: xxxpx, width: 200, height: 200}');
}.bind(this));

#target {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: cyan;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
}
#trace {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
#example {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    width:5px;
    height:5px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 100;
}
.rotation {
    -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

Comment: As per my understanding rotation does not change the position of the div i.e. x and y .. it will change its angle not the position and btw you have not described your problem properly .. your question title and body ask for two different things .. *Title : 'after it's been rotated?'* .. *Body : 'before rotation was applied'* ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizing [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/), try

```
document.getElementById('btn-coordinate-notrotated')
.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
     // solution here    
     var styles = $("#target")
                  .css(["height", "width", "top"
                      , "bottom", "left", "right"
                      , "background", "position"]);
    $("<div />", {"class":"clone", "css":styles}).appendTo("body");
    alert('{top: ' + styles.top + ',left: '
          + styles.left + ', right: ' 
          + styles.right + ', width: '
          + styles.width + ', height: '
          + styles.height + '}');
}.bind(this));
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/akycc4t1/9/

Comment: @Shikkediel See OP at  _" Other methods or idea area also welcome."_ , `jquery` tag ?

Comment: @Shikkediel fwiw, composed a "pure" `js` version as well, utilizing `getComputedStyle` , and a `for in` loop . Posted "jQuery" solution to , possibly, add varied approach - after noting above portions of OP. Cheers:)

Comment: thanks guys for your ideas. Do you have an idea how would you calculate this coordinate also mathematically?

Comment: Related to my question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234132/how-to-calculate-cartesian-coordinates-for-an-element-after-rotation-has-been-ap

Answer (score 0):

```
// solution here
var style = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('target'));
alert('{top: ' + style.top + ', left: ' + style.left + ', width: 200, height: 200}');
```

Comment: please explain the answer